# Select default value of column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I will not go deep in details.
I have Java program which is creating tables in Database. The thing is that when table is created one of the fields get default value. So when I am adding elements to this field I want to select default value. Now loading of all element's ID is:

```
SELECT distinct(codeKind) FROM [table_name];
```

I want to be something like this:

```
SELECT [default value of column codeKind] from [table_name];
```

I checked many of answer of other similiar questions but none of them is OK.

Thanks.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT codeKind FROM ...` to make code clearer!

Answer (score 3):

I also find solution:

```
select COLUMN_DEFAULT
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='my_db' and TABLE_NAME='my_table' and COLUMN_NAME='my_column'
```

Comment: It shows the result of table creation ddl ( such as  create table my_table ( my_column default 0, col2 int .... ) ), if you leave the column value as blank in the insert statement, then the value is automatically populated as zero.

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce`

```
select coalesce(codeKind,<def_value>)
```

*Alternatively you can set a fixed value for table's creation `DDL` such as*

*`create table my_table ( my_column default 0, col2 int .... )` , if you leave the column value as blank in the insert statement, then the value is automatically populated as zero.*

Comment: The coalesce() function returns the first non-null value in a list. My table is empty at first, I am not sure how this would work.

Comment: The square brackets make me suspect this is a sqlserver answer do you have a reference for mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon Ok, is it better as a notation :) ?

Comment: Not sure, if the column has been assigned a default value then it won't be null I think the question is give me the rows where the column value = the default value for that column.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov sure as you mentioned, default value already stands for replacing null values with a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
drop table if exists t;
 create table t
 (id int auto_increment primary key,size int, sizecaption1 int default 10, sizecaption2 int, sizecaption3 int);

 insert into t (id,size) values 
 (1,22);
 insert into t values
 (2,22,22,22,22),
 (3,22,22,30,20),
 (4,22,1,2,3);

 select * from t where sizecaption1 = 
 (
 select column_default from information_schema.columns 
 where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox' and column_default is not null
 ) ;

+----+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | size | sizecaption1 | sizecaption2 | sizecaption3 |
+----+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |   22 |           10 |         NULL |         NULL |
+----+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```